# How to not allow other user to interpret my remote session?

Tags: remote-desktop, batch-file, remote-access, remote-assistance, remote-login

In my work sometimes i need to remotely access a user pc to do some work using the default windows remote desktop application.

my problem is that when a user tries to login into his account it will log me out amd let that user login.

I am looking for a way to not allow anyone log me out until I finish my work

For example
If I login with administrator account it will not allow anyone else to interpret me until i logout

Is their something I can do? If no

Can I make batch file that will for example change temporary other users accounts password when administrator account access a pc so he can't login and when administrator user logout it will rest the password? 
Note user password are not known for me

I'm working on Windows xp professional sp1 i know it is dead but that i have to deal with it.

Comment: Windows xp sp1 i know it is dead but that i have to deal with it.

Comment: Are any of the other users that need to logon members of the local Administrators group? What edition of XP?

Comment: No they don't need to login as local administrator group and i am using windows xp professional sp1